# When I have 100 columns, what should I do to retrieve the columns?

Tags: django, model

Hello I have a question for django orm ~!

table model is this

```
author |    ca1    | ca2  | ca3  | ca4   |  ca5  | ca6  | … | ca100
mike   | rabbit    | bird | shark| mouse | dog   | cat  |
```

When I search using the search term tiger

To get the next search result

```
mike, ca5, dog
```

What should I do with orm?
What should I do with orm?
What should I do with orm?
What should I do with orm?
What should I do with orm?

thank you for let me know~!
thank you for let me know~!
thank you for let me know~!
thank you for let me know~!
thank you for let me know~!

```
class CategoryNick(models.Model):
    ca_subtitle = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="my category info")
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=True)
    ca1 = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="ca1")
    ca2 = models.CharField(max_length=50 , default="ca2")
    ca3 = models.CharField(max_length=50 , default="ca3")
    ca4 = models.CharField(max_length=50 , default="ca4")
    ca5 = models.CharField(max_length=50 , default="ca5")
    ca6 = models.CharField(max_length=50 , default="ca6")
    ca7 = models.CharField(max_length=50 , default="ca7")
    ca8 = models.CharField(max_length=50 , default="ca8")
    ca9 = models.CharField(max_length=50 , default="ca9")
    ca10 = models.CharField(max_length=50 , default="ca10")
    ca11 = models.CharField(max_length=50 , default="ca11")
    ca12 = models.CharField(max_length=50 , default="ca12")
    ca13 = models.CharField(max_length=50 , default="ca13")
    ca14 = models.CharField(max_length=50 , default="ca14")
    ca15 = models.CharField(max_length=50 , default="ca15")
    ca16 = models.CharField(max_length=50 , default="ca16")
    ca17 = models.CharField(max_length=50 , default="ca17")
    ca18 = models.CharField(max_length=50 , default="ca18")
    ca19 = models.CharField(max_length=50 , default="ca19")
    ca20 = models.CharField(max_length=50 , default="ca20")
    ca21 = models.CharField(max_length=50 , default="ca21")
    ca22 = models.CharField(max_length=50 , default="ca22")
    ca23 = models.CharField(max_length=50 , default="ca23")
    ca24 = models.CharField(max_length=50 , default="ca24")
    ca25 = models.CharField(max_length=50 , default="ca25")
    ca26 = models.CharField(max_length=50 , default="ca26")
    ca27 = models.CharField(max_length=50 , default="ca27")
    ca28 = models.CharField(max_length=50 , default="ca28")
    ca29 = models.CharField(max_length=50 , default="ca29")
    ca30 = models.CharField(max_length=50 , default="ca30")
    ca31 = models.CharField(max_length=50 , default="ca31")
    ca32 = models.CharField(max_length=50 , default="ca32")
    ca33 = models.CharField(max_length=50 , default="ca33")
    ca34 = models.CharField(max_length=50 , default="ca34")
    ca35 = models.CharField(max_length=50 , default="ca35")
    ca36 = models.CharField(max_length=50 , default="ca36")
    ca37 = models.CharField(max_length=50 , default="ca37")
    ca38 = models.CharField(max_length=50 , default="ca38")
    ca39 = models.CharField(max_length=50 , default="ca39")
    ca40 = models.CharField(max_length=50 , default="ca40")
    ca41 = models.CharField(max_length=50 , default="ca41")
    ca42 = models.CharField(max_length=50 , default="ca42")
    ca43 = models.CharField(max_length=50 , default="ca43")
    ca44 = models.CharField(max_length=50 , default="ca44")
    ca45 = models.CharField(max_length=50 , default="ca45")
    ca46 = models.CharField(max_length=50 , default="ca46")
    ca47 = models.CharField(max_length=50 , default="ca47")
    ca48 = models.CharField(max_length=50 , default="ca48")
    ca49 = models.CharField(max_length=50 , default="ca49")
    ca50 = models.CharField(max_length=50 , default="ca50")
    ca51 = models.CharField(max_length=50 , default="ca51")
    ca52 = models.CharField(max_length=50 , default="ca52")
    ca53 = models.CharField(max_length=50 , default="ca53")
    ca54 = models.CharField(max_length=50 , default="ca54")
    ca55 = models.CharField(max_length=50 , default="ca55")
    ca56 = models.CharField(max_length=50 , default="ca56")
    ca57 = models.CharField(max_length=50 , default="ca57")
    ca58 = models.CharField(max_length=50 , default="ca58")
    ca59 = models.CharField(max_length=50 , default="ca59")
    ca60 = models.CharField(max_length=50 , default="ca60")
    ca61 = models.CharField(max_length=50 , default="ca61")
    ca62 = models.CharField(max_length=50 , default="ca62")
    ca63 = models.CharField(max_length=50 , default="ca63")
    ca64 = models.CharField(max_length=50 , default="ca64")
    ca65 = models.CharField(max_length=50 , default="ca65")
    ca66 = models.CharField(max_length=50 , default="ca66")
    ca67 = models.CharField(max_length=50 , default="ca67")
    ca68 = models.CharField(max_length=50 , default="ca68")
    ca69 = models.CharField(max_length=50 , default="ca69")
    ca70 = models.CharField(max_length=50 , default="ca70")
    ca71 = models.CharField(max_length=50 , default="ca71")
    ca72 = models.CharField(max_length=50 , default="ca72")
    ca73 = models.CharField(max_length=50 , default="ca73")
    ca74 = models.CharField(max_length=50 , default="ca74")
    ca75 = models.CharField(max_length=50 , default="ca75")
    ca76 = models.CharField(max_length=50 , default="ca76")
    ca77 = models.CharField(max_length=50 , default="ca77")
    ca78 = models.CharField(max_length=50 , default="ca78")
    ca79 = models.CharField(max_length=50 , default="ca79")
    ca80 = models.CharField(max_length=50 , default="ca80")
    ca81 = models.CharField(max_length=50 , default="ca81")
    ca82 = models.CharField(max_length=50 , default="ca82")
    ca83 = models.CharField(max_length=50 , default="ca83")
    ca84 = models.CharField(max_length=50 , default="ca84")
    ca85 = models.CharField(max_length=50 , default="ca85")
    ca86 = models.CharField(max_length=50 , default="ca86")
    ca87 = models.CharField(max_length=50 , default="ca87")
    ca88 = models.CharField(max_length=50 , default="ca88")
    ca89 = models.CharField(max_length=50 , default="ca89")
    ca90 = models.CharField(max_length=50 , default="ca90")
    ca91 = models.CharField(max_length=50 , default="ca91")
    ca92 = models.CharField(max_length=50 , default="ca92")
    ca93 = models.CharField(max_length=50 , default="ca93")
    ca94 = models.CharField(max_length=50 , default="ca94")
    ca95 = models.CharField(max_length=50 , default="ca95")
    ca96 = models.CharField(max_length=50 , default="ca96")
    ca97 = models.CharField(max_length=50 , default="ca97")
    ca98 = models.CharField(max_length=50 , default="ca98")
    ca99 = models.CharField(max_length=50 , default="ca99")
```

[image]

Comment: There is something very wrong with your modelling. There's no reason to have 100 different `ca` columns. Apply normalization rules and split them off into a separate model linked via ForeignKey.

Answer (score 1):

watch this

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/meta/#django.db.models.options.Options.get_field

let me tell you that all the models already have the __meta class(by inheritance) which is created automatically and it contain fields variable that stores all the fields name so by using that we are calling this get_field() which gives us the field value

```
>>> from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# A field on the model
>>> User._meta.get_field('username')
<django.db.models.fields.CharField: username>

# A field from another model that has a relation with the current model
>>> User._meta.get_field('logentry')
<ManyToOneRel: admin.logentry>

# A non existent field
>>> User._meta.get_field('does_not_exist')
Traceback (most recent call last):
    ...
FieldDoesNotExist: User has no field named 'does_not_exist'
```

Comment: thanks but i can't understand this yet I will learn more about the concepts you have given me. Thank you.

Comment: @HyK if it works for you accept the ans for no more confusion